# Navicat: import data from another server without problems

Tags: mysql, import, navicat

I have a table on another server that is formatted with millions of rows like this.

```
+-------+-----+------+
| Name  | Age | Type |
+-------+-----+------+
| Adam  |  29 | A    |
| Bob   |  18 | B    |
| Carla |  25 | O    |
+-------+-----+------+
```

I also have three Navicat import profiles that grabs the information from this server and stores it locally in different databases.

```
SELECT * FROM tble WHERE type = 'A';
SELECT * FROM tble WHERE type = 'B';
SELECT * FROM tble WHERE type = 'O';
```

Each query takes about 15 minutes to run. What methods are available to me to have each them run and finish with a respectable time? Would I have to worry about lock issues?

Comment: Do you have significantly different numbers of rows returned for some queries? If you run a test returning all the rows, does that also take about the same time? What if, instead of a SQL query, you tried to simply copy/FTP a file from one server to the other (one of comparable size to the output from your queries). How long does that take? These will help you diagnose if the issue is one of network bandwidth, or of the queries themselves.

Answer (score 0):

"Remember where you left off".  That is, have a monotonically increasing column on the table and keep track of how much you grabbed so far.  Only grab stuff beyond that.  Be sure to have an index on that column.